# Populating a page from Data table in modal panel

Tags: jsf, richfaces, myfaces

I'm trying to get some data from a datatable in `rich:modal` panel

The whole flow is as follows

- When clicking on search button on main page, a modal panel pops up with appropriate data & check box
- Till this point the application is working fine
- After clicking on ok button, selected data should be populated into main page. This is where the code fails

I tried stuff like `getRowData`, `getValues`, etc. but in vain. This could be done by keeping the bean in session scope but I have to keep this bean in request scope using Apache MyFaces JSF 1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways comes to mind:

1. Pass an extra request parameter (the search string and the page number?) so that the bean knows which data to preload.
2. Make use of [MyFaces Orchestra](http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/) to create a conversation scope which lies in between request and session scope and is exactly the scope you're looking for this particular functional requirement.

Comment: Thnx BalusC, 

I just referred to your blog
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html

It is helpful and the code works fine when on a page but as i move the same code to modal panel some how i don't get values from these methods (getRowData,getValue,etc), Even the ValueChangeListener doesn't work ... :((

I will try looking into Myfaces Orchestra, hope it solves my problem